Trying to find left and right minimums in a graph knowing the peaks
I need to calculate the Area under some specific portions of a graph, and I've already identified the peaks in my graph because my idea is finding them and then trying to find the left and the right lowest point to later integrate with from scipy.integrate import trapezoid to find the area.
My data is structured as showed in the image. I have 3 columns: a unix timestamp, a pH value, and the frequency of the swimming pool pump which keeps the pH below 7.4.
I'm using the find_peaks function from Scipy and I have determined these values to be my peaks in the pulse column:
[    76    654   1567   3741   5658   6259   9284  12959  14424  15369
  16182  19898  24427  26497  27020  28392  31673  32164  32308  32441
  32919  33171  33226  33395  33584  34403  37442  37821  38295  38658
  39127  41645  42721  43241  44220  47337  48878  50036  50336  54291
  54648  55368  56257  58767  58893  59926  60850  61535  63231  64580
  66107  66190  66807  66878  68360  69080  70517  71883  72359  72653
  72725  73014  73412  74399  77674  78188  78456  78809  79174  84175
  88802  89698  90503  95448  97545  99026 100401 101071 102192 104737
 104782 106345 106925 107737 108584 109238 112963 113562 114415 114510
 117724 117796 118523 118573 118786 118890 119141 119335 119590 122015
 123226 124753 133455 136470 139130]

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime, timezone
from scipy.integrate import trapezoid
from scipy.signal import find_peaks, argrelextrema

# Read your dataset
df = pd.read_csv('Dataset_05_unix.csv')

# Ensure the data is sorted by 'x'
df = df.sort_values(by='timestamp')

# Define the start and end times of the period you're interested in
start_time = datetime.strptime('2024-02-21 15:54:32+00:00', '%Y-%m-%d          %H:%M:%S%z').timestamp()
end_time = datetime.strptime('2024-03-21 15:54:22+00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z').timestamp()

filtered_df = df[(df['timestamp'] >= start_time) & (df['timestamp'] <= end_time)]

# Extract filtered x_values and y_values
filtered_x_values = filtered_df['timestamp'].tolist()
filtered_y_values = filtered_df['pulse'].tolist()

# Calculate the area under the curve for the filtered data
area = trapezoid(filtered_y_values, filtered_x_values)
print("Area under the curve for the specified period:", area)

# Apply the moving average
filtered_df['smoothed_pulse'] = filtered_df['pulse'].rolling(window=5).mean()

# Find peaks in the smoothed data
peaks, _ = find_peaks(filtered_df['smoothed_pulse'].tolist(), height=5) 

print(peaks)
print(len(peaks))
print(len(filtered_df))

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(filtered_df['timestamp'], filtered_df['smoothed_pulse'], label='Smoothed Data',     color='red')

# Plot the peaks
plt.plot(filtered_df['timestamp'].iloc[peaks], filtered_df['smoothed_pulse'].iloc[peaks], "x",label='Peaks') 


plt.legend()
plt.show()

The question is, is there a method to get the left and right lowest points in a precise way at this point?
The difficulty is that it could find multiple 'false' minimums which are not the ones I need.

Are those time stamps or indices in that list, and at what point(s) are you referring to? Presumably they are indices to time stamps.

Welcome to SO, please make your question a [mcve], add the image you are referencing in your post and add data (copy paste or link, no screenshot).

If you pass the prominence argument, you can get left and right bases as a property of the peaks. This has the advantage of simplicity, but the drawback that this definition of right/left minimums allows the areas being integrated to overlap. I'm unsure if you care about this.

You can use find_peaks(-x) to essentially flip your data (where x is your data) and find the indices of the 'minimas'. Though you would then need to iterate over this list of minimas and identify which pair of minimas match with the maxima in question using their indices.

My data is structured as showed in the image.... What image?
